# Extract values from dictionary to array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a Dictionary in Swift with the next format:

```
(lldb) po dataMid
▿ 1 element
 ▿ 0 : 2 elements
  - key : "mids"
  ▿ value : 2 elements
   ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
     - key : checksum
     - value :dkskskdkdksksksnsnskd
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
     - key : server_version
     - value : @(#) $version: 1.8.1 $date: Sep 8 2019 10:15:04
   ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
     - key : checksum
     - value : 02ekekekwkskslsld
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
     - key : server_version
     - value : @(#) $version: 1.0.4 $date: Sep 5 2018 08:17:51
```

All I want is to extract just the strings with key "server_version" into an array to show them in a tableView

Comment: `if let mids = dataMid["mids"] as? [String: Any], let serverVersion = mids["server_version"] as? String { print("serverVersion: \(serverVersion)}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compactMap` function to extract value from array of dictionary.

Try below the below code

```
let dict : [String : AnyObject] = ["mids": dataMid as AnyObject]
    
if let arrValue = dict["mids"] as? [[String : Any]] {
            
    if let arrServerVersionValue = arrValue.compactMap({$0["server_version"]}) as? [String] {
       print("All Values of Server Version Key = \(arrServerVersionValue)")
    }
}
```